# How would the DTO look like when domain model have abstract properties?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a RESTful API, in which the entities are persisted in Azure Storage Table service.

One of my entities is `Tenant` entity and it would look like this:

```
public class TenantEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name
    {
        get => PartitionKey;
        set
        {
            PartitionKey = value;
            RowKey = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string DefaultActionSerialized
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DefaultAction);
        set => DefaultAction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScheduledAction>(value);
    }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public ScheduledAction DefaultAction { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ScheduledActionJsonConverter))]
public abstract class ScheduledAction
{
    public abstract ScheduledActionType ActionType { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum ScheduledActionType
{
    StorageQueueMessage,
    Webhook
}
```

Please note the `DefaultAction` property which is of type `ScheduledAction`.
My original thought was that there will be several *ScheduledActions* supported, like putting a message in queue, or calling a webhook etc.

However, I'm not sure how would the DTO of the `Tenant` entity would look like.
Shall I replicate and create a DTO for the abstract `ScheduledAction` class, and then do the same for each of its inheritors?

If you would model it differently, then I'd be happy to hear about this as well - but please for the sake of experiencing DTOs, I'd be happy to have an answer for this question as well :)

Right now, the `TenantDto` class looks like this:

```
public class TenantDto
{
    [Required]
    [FromRoute(Name = "tenant")]
    [JsonProperty("TenantName")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 24, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string TenantName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("ScheduledAction")]
    public ScheduledAction ScheduledAction { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator TenantEntity(TenantDto tenantDto)
    {
        return new TenantEntity
        {
            Name = tenantDto.TenantName,
            DefaultAction = tenantDto.ScheduledAction,
        };
    }
}
```

It references the domain model `ScheduledAction` which I know is bad practice, but could not find a solution which makes more sense to me.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: IMO DTOs should be standalone.  You might think you need some shared functionality now, but in 5 years time when 20 different developers have ripped the original logic apart, you might spend more time keeping things compiling than it's worth.  Just split everything up now.

Comment: Oh, and your `TenentEntity`, use AutoMapper.  It's simple and will catch any updates automatically (assuming field names are the same).

Comment: I prefer doing it manually this time, just to understand how to work with DTOs.

Comment: OK, that's fine but I'd use an extension class instead of the operator constructor, at the moment your DTO is more than a simple class and permanently linked to the entity, which is bad.  (again, my opinion).

Comment: If the property is called `ScheduledAction` there's absolutely no reason to use `[JsonProperty("ScheduledAction")]`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about decorating your DTOs with attributes. Considering SRP, the responsibility of a DTO is to transfer data. And how about if the clients do not understand the attributes or if they are not a web client?

Comment: The clients will send JSON's of this structure, this is my way to validate the JSONs are correct.
Where would you put these validations?